# Android NFC: How to setup password and auth on NFC TAG?

Tags: react-native, nfc, core-nfc

I have ntag213, using react-native-nfc-manager and using it with andriod, at documentation for my tag https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf I understand firstly I need to authenticate first with command 0x1B to 0x2B and my password: 0xFF1FFFFF

```
let cmd = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? NfcManager.sendMifareCommandIOS : NfcManager.transceive; resp = await cmd(0x1B,0x2B,0xFF1FFFFF);
```

But I got error on my screen and dont understand next steps after auth. Please explain how it works
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 problems with the command you are trying to send.

1) transceive only takes a byte array and `0xFF1FFFFF` is not a byte array but a big number which would need a double to store.

Thus you are trying to send (byte,byte,double) and the error message it cannot cast the double to an array.

2) the `pwd_auth` command only take a byte array of 5 bytes, 1 byte command + 4 bytes password so don't know why you have `0x2B` in there.

So Try

`let cmd = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? NfcManager.sendMifareCommandIOS : NfcManager.transceive; resp = await cmd([0x1B,0xFF,0x1F,0xFF,0xFF]);`

Then check that you the PACK is correct and that you did not get a NACK

I don't use passwords in my App but I believe you are then authenticated to send normal commands until you close the connection or the card goes out of range.

Comment: I tried and got this error.
`Java.lang.double cannot be caset to com.faceboook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeArray`
So that 0xFF,0x1F,0xFF,0xFF mean every byte of password?

Comment: Sorry forgot brackets to make it an array, fixed now

Comment: I forgot it my topic too, but unfortunately i got new error: `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): "transceive fail"` Maybe you can advice me some forum with info? because I didnt find any info in google

Comment: You are doing this in a `try` `catch` block?

Comment: yes, `testAuth = async()=>{ 
        try{
            let tech = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? NfcTech.MifareIOS : NfcTech.NfcA;
            let resp = await NfcManager.requestTechnology(tech, {
                alertMessage: 'Ready to do some custom Mifare cmd!'
            }); 
            let cmd = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? NfcManager.sendMifareCommandIOS : NfcManager.transceive;
            resp = await cmd([0x1B,0xFF]); 
            console.warn(resp);
        }catch(err){
            if(err) throw err;
        }
    }
    `

Comment: Does the `resp` variable have any contents? This might be something like an IO error or Card left field error or the card could have responded with a NACK with why it rejected your transceive (I assume you have tested that the read/write app you linked in the previous question works correctly with your cards)